# networkxのノードが表示されない

Tags: python, python3, networkx

pythonのnetworkxを使って指定した座標でノードをプロットしようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。エッジを指定しないとうまくいかないのですが解決策はないでしょうか。

```
import networkx as nx
n = 18
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(n-1)
pos = { 0: (0, 8),  
         1: (0, 7),  
         2: (0, 6), 
         3: (0, 5),   9: (1, 5),  12: (2, 5), 15:(3, 5),           
         4: (0, 4),  10: (1, 4),  13: (2, 4), 16:(3, 4),
         5: (0, 3),  11: (1, 3),  14: (2, 3), 17:(3, 3),
         6: (0, 2),
         7: (0, 1),
         8: (0, 0),  }
nx.draw(G, pos)
#nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

辞書(dict)型インスタンスの `pos` からキーを拾ってグラフに追加すればよろしいのではないでしょうか。

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
pos = {
   0: (0, 8),  
   1: (0, 7),  
   2: (0, 6), 
   3: (0, 5),   9: (1, 5),  12: (2, 5), 15:(3, 5),           
   4: (0, 4),  10: (1, 4),  13: (2, 4), 16:(3, 4),
   5: (0, 3),  11: (1, 3),  14: (2, 3), 17:(3, 3),
   6: (0, 2),
   7: (0, 1),
   8: (0, 0),
}

G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
nx.draw(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

[image: 18個のノード]

Answer (score 1):

`G.add_node(n-1)`だけが行われていて、それでは`17`のノードが1つだけ存在する状態ではないでしょうか？
そのために１個だけ表示されるのでしょう。

例えば`G.add_node(n-1)`の代わりに以下のいずれかで18個のノードを作っておけば良いと思われます。

ループで順次作って登録する：

```
for i in range(n):
    G.add_node(i)
```

リストを作って登録する：

```
nodes = [i for i in range(n)]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
```